# ES6 - Confused about processing order of Promise

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I've got this code:

```
let p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        resolve({dogs: ['Fido', 'Spot']});
    }, 2000);
});

p1.then(function (val) {
    console.log('first then');
    console.dir(val);
    return _.extend(val, {cats: ['Fluffy', 'Whiskers']});
}).then(function (val) {
    console.log('second then');
    console.dir(val);
});
```

The unexpected console output shows:

[image]

I don't understand how `cats` could possibly be part of the value before it's actually appended into the object. The results printed in the second `then` make sense to me though. Am I missing something?

Comment: See the `i` popup in the console.  You're seeing the later-mutated object.

Comment: It says "Object state below is captured upon first expansion." I don't even know what that means...

Comment: is _.extend() from underscore.js?

Comment: @keheliya I rejected your tag edit, as the question is not really about Underscore and Underscore's usage here is irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: This has nothing to do with promises and everything to do with how the console works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [console.log() async or sync?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the `cats` property to the same object you already logged.

As the `i` icon tells you, the console only reads the properties of the object when you actually expand it.

Comment: Because serializing stuff is slow. If you logged a really large object often, it would bring your tab to a grinding halt. Plus not all objects are trivially copyable, so even just making a copy isn't well defined. If you want it at the time, just do `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));` instead, or do `_.extend({}, val, {cats: ['Fluffy', 'Whiskers']});` so you don't mutate the original value.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I agree JSON.stringify is a possible workaround.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Please don't forget to vote to close as duplicate :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is a bug in console.log by ES6 Promises. It waits for a few seconds before it logs the value of your object, that's why it contains the cats. If I remember well, this bug happens in firefox. I don't know how it behaves by the other browsers.

Comment: It's just with `console.log` though. If I do an `alert`, it works as expected. And this console issue appears in both FF and Chrome.

Comment: @ffxsam Yepp. This is a known bug. I don't think you need to report it, maybe add a +1 somewhere, if you find the existing reports.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Ye we all know that: `bug + won'tfix = feature`.

Comment: I kind of meant it honestly really. See my other comment. It might be a little surprising at times, but there isn't really any way you could do deep introspection of an object and NOT do it like it is.